# copy vs deepcopy: semantics

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, deep-copy

My class represents states of various systems. Each instance has two attributes: one is a container shared between all the states of the same system, and the other is a container that is unique to each instance.

A copy of a state should reuse the "shared" attribute, but create a deep copy of the "unique" attribute. This is really the only copy semantics that makes sense (it's natural that the copy of a state is a state of the same system).

I want to create the least surprise for people who read and maintain my code. Should I override `__deepcopy__` or `__copy__` for my purposes?

Comment: `__deepcopy__` if you are taking a poll...

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a consensus view :) And it might still be, after everyone gets a chance to see everyone's response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it really necessary to use the copy module for copying instances of this class?  I would argue that instead of overriding `__copy__` or `__deepcopy__` you should create a `copy` method for your class that returns a new object using the copy semantics you defined.

If for some consistency reason you do need to use the copy module, then in my opinion `__deepcopy__` is more appropriate.  If it is a defined behavior of the class that all instances share one of the containers, then it is reasonable to assume that an implementation of `__deepcopy__` would respect that.

Comment: I'm fine with not using the `copy` module. But if I define a `copy` method, wouldn't readers assume it's a shallow copy like it is for `dict` or `set`?

Comment: @max, is your class a subclass of `dict` or `set`?  If not, then readers should not assume that a `copy` method for your class is supposed to imitate `copy` from a built-in type.

Comment: @max: I think you will always surprise some readers, since your intended semantics are neither fully shallow nor fully deep. But of all the possible places to define custom copy semantics, I would think a class's `copy` method is the one which is most likely to be customized. If fully shallow and fully deep semantics truly *do not make sense* for your class, then why not override both of them? (You could make `__copy__` as well as `__deepcopy__` call the class's `copy`.)

Comment: @F.J: So, I feel pretty comfortable with a `state.copy` method. I probably should leave the __deepcopy__ overridden still, since otherwise someone doing `copy.deepcopy({state1, state2})` will end up copying the "shared" attribute unnecessarily.

Comment: @John Y: I'll probably have `__copy__` raise an exception since there's really no point in calling it.

Comment: @max: By the way, if you are worried that `deepcopy()` implies unconditional fully deep semantics (and would thus surprise readers when this is not the case), be reassured by this section of the `copy` module documentation: (paraphrasing) "Because deep copy copies *everything* it may copy too much, e.g., administrative data structures that should be shared even between copies. The `deepcopy()` function avoids this problem by letting user-defined classes override the copying operation or the set of components copied."

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to your situation?

```
import copy

class Foo(object):
    shared = [[]]
    def __init__(self):
        self.perinstance = [[]]
```

If so, then it appears you do not need to define `__copy__` or `__deepcopy__`, since the default behavior of `copy.deepcopy` shares class attributes and deepcopies instance attributes:

```
x = Foo()
z = copy.deepcopy(x)
assert id(z.shared) == id(x.shared)
assert id(z.shared[0]) == id(x.shared[0])
assert id(z.perinstance) != id(x.perinstance)
assert id(z.perinstance[0]) != id(x.perinstance[0])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my shared attribute is an instance attribute. I was imprecise in my explanation. The "shared" attribute can vary between instances, but only if they correspond to different systems. The copy semantics (as you would expect) creates a copy of a state from the same system, thus it has the same value of the shared attribute. I'm updating the question to clarify this.